# Jenkins Windows Slave not compiling because its using a JRE and not JDK

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I've been searching all over for a solution to this. I have Jenkins running on Linux server. I created a Jenkins job and deployed my code on the Jenkins machine. Everything works great. I added a Windows slave machine and moved my job to the windows machine. I continue to get this error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running        
on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

I ensured the JAVA_HOME was set.

I also set the tools location for the windows slave:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin
```

Still the same error when it tries to compile the code on the Windows slave machine.

I was wondering is this a maven issue, where I need to define in the POM.xml the location of the JDK?

Comment: You're pointing the tools on the slave at the jre...

Comment: To compile code, you need JDK. Nothing to do with maven.  Have you configured jenkins to download JDK automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is:

1) In the job you are running on the slave machine you need to set the JDK you want to build with.

2) Configure the slave server, add the JDK8 in the Tools section